# What is innovation here?

Tags: prior-art-request

In reference to the patent: [WO2017209845A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2017209845A1)

Scan detection is a well-known very old technique. https://github.com/eldondev/Snort/blob/master/rules/scan.rules are open source rules. Detection is through well-known scan detection technique deception or no deception scan can be detected through network packets.